# Unity C# How do you save color from colour texture as playerprefs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors

I am making a character creator for a game project I currently working on. I am using Texture2D to use as a color picker for picking colors for hair, skin, e.g. I could save it using DonDestroyOnLoad, but I want to know how to save it as PlayerPrefs. I originally got the code from a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKhFYxUNL6A&list=PLiW_iGwxIxj_lMxm1UJeGNYJbqZ828UYx&index=2&t=1045s. The original person said that I could use ToHtmlStringRGB and TryParseHtmlString, but I not sure how to implement it into the script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using System;
using UnityEngine.Events;

[Serializable]
public class ColorEvent : UnityEvent<Color> { }
public class ColourPicker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI DebugText;
    public ColorEvent OnColorPreview;
    public ColorEvent OnColorSelect;
    RectTransform Rect;
    Texture2D ColorTexture;
  
    void Start()
    {
        Rect = GetComponent<RectTransform>();

        ColorTexture = GetComponent<Image>().mainTexture as Texture2D;
    }
   
    void Update()
    {
        if (RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint(Rect, Input.mousePosition))
        {
            Vector2 delta;
            RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(Rect, Input.mousePosition, null, out delta);

            string debug = "mousePosition=" + Input.mousePosition;
            debug += "<br>delta" + delta;

            float width = Rect.rect.width;
            float height = Rect.rect.height;
            delta += new Vector2(width * .5f, height * .5f);
            debug += "<br>offset delta" + delta;

            float x = Mathf.Clamp(delta.x / width, 0f, 1f);
            float y = Mathf.Clamp(delta.y / height, 0f, 1f);
            debug += "<br>x=" + x + " y=" + y;

            int texX = Mathf.RoundToInt(x * ColorTexture.width);
            int texY = Mathf.RoundToInt(y * ColorTexture.height);
            debug += "<br>texX=" + texX + " texY=" + texY;

            Color color = ColorTexture.GetPixel(texX, texY);
            DebugText.color = color;
            DebugText.text = debug;


            OnColorPreview?.Invoke(color);

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                OnColorSelect?.Invoke(color);
            }

          

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to convert the color to string and save to PlayerPrefs:

```
var colorHexCode = ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGBA(color);
PlayerPrefs.SetString("CharacterColor", colorHexCode);
```

Then later, you can get the HTML string value of the color from the PlayerPrefs like this:

```
var colorHexCode = PlayerPrefs.GetString("CharacterColor");
```

and convert to Color:

```
Color color = Color.black;
if(ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString(colorHexCode, out color))
{
  // Do something if color parsing is successful
}
```

Comment: It sounds like OP already knew these but asks us how/where to place it in his code .. `the original person said that I could use ToHtmlStringRGB and TryParseHtmlString, but I not sure how to implement it into the script.`